# Clearing Combo Box with Remote Store after Select All + Delete / Backspace in IE

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have an ExtJS combo box (of version 4.1) with a remote store. There is a requirement to clear the combo box and store when the combo box is emptied.

To do this, I implemented a function that clears the combo box and store on keypress and change events (see code below).

However, the combo box refuses to empty itself when a user selects all (shift+home if the cursor is at the end or shift+end if the cursor is at the beginning) and then presses backspace / delete. In such case, the combo box always populates itself with the last selected value when it loses focus. This happens only in IE (which my clients use).

Any idea how to prevent the combo box from doing that?

Code snippet below:

```
// clearExistingInput function (called from combo box)
clearExistingInput: function(ths, newVal) {
    if(newVal === null){
        ths.store.removeAll();
        ths.clearValue();
    }
}

// combo box configuration
{
    labelAlign : 'right',
    xtype: 'combo',
    store: comboStore,
    filterOnLoad: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    hideTrigger:true,
    minChars :1,            
    size:15,
    queryDelay: 20, 
    queryCaching: false,
    // enable paging with width that fits the paging toolbar
    matchFieldWidth: false,
    listConfig: {
        width: 220,
        height: 300, 
        autoHeight: true
    },
    maxWidth: 35,
    pageSize: true,

    enableKeyEvents:true,
    listeners:{
        'keypress':function(ths,e){ 
            if (e.getKey() == e.DELETE || e.getKey() == e.BACKSPACE) {
                this.up('formFilter').clearExistingInput(ths, ths.value);
            }
         },
        'change': function(ths,newVal,OldVal,eOpts){
            this.up('formFilter').clearExistingInput(ths, newVal);
        }
    }
}

// combo box store
comboStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      pageSize: 10,
      autoLoad: false,
      proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'Service/data',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            }
        },
        fields: [
          {name: 'data', type : 'String'}
        ]
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `forceSelection` to false? The Combo's beforeBlur method calls assertValue which will reset the combo's value to the `lastSelection` if `forceSelection` is true. According to Ext's docs it's supposed to be false by default, but it's something you could check.

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting `forceSelection` to false. It didn't have any effect.

Comment: Without debugging the code, I couldn't really guess as to why this is happening. Your posted code looks fine. Although `this.up('formFilter').clearExistingInput(ths, ths.value)` looks a little suspicious. If you're clearing the existing input, what is `ths.value` and why are you passing it?

Comment: `ths.value` is the value of the combo box. It is passed because I'd like to ensure the combo box is empty before I clear the store (this was the requirement). If the `ths.clearValue()` in `clearExistingInput` throws you off -- that part may seem redundant indeed -- I put it in a vain attempt to not make the combo box value come back in the scenario I'm having problem with.